# Not informative exception info on xCode 4.6

Tags: ios, xcode, exception, crash

If my application crashes I take the information on `All Output` window like this:

> Uncaught exception: *** -[NSPlaceholderMutableString initWithString:]:
>   nil argument 2013-02-28 04:09:15.209 Cpp[948:907]**  Terminating app
>   due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '
>   **-[NSPlaceholderMutableString initWithString:]: nil argument'
>   *** First throw call stack: (0x3336b3e7 0x3b05c963 0x3336b307 0x33bf0eb5 0x33c0ab8b 0xd16ed 0xd0a63 0xc3e79 0xc5cfd 0x3336ead4
>   0x332c628f 0x332c5de3 0x39be081b 0x3336d737 0x332c5208 0x3336ead4
>   0x332c628f 0x3930bc5b 0x39348ce1 0x333408f7 0x3334015d 0x3333ef2f
>   0x332b223d 0x332b20c9 0x36e9033b 0x351ce2b9 0xc0109 0xc00a0)
>   libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an exception (lldb)

And the call stack like this:

[image]

Where is there something helpful to fix the issue? Where is there my method on call stack? Where is there my line of code? What's wrong with xCode and how to fix this problem?

Comment: Look for the slider below the stack trace you posted. Move the slider so the stack trace shows more detail.

Comment: rmaddy, I posted all data from that window, don't think I'm a fool.

Comment: Look at the screen shot you posted. Look at Thread 1. Notice it shows lines 0, 13, 14, and 15. Where are lines 1-12? In Xcode, when you hit a breakpoint or crash, look at the bottom of the screen showing the stack traces. There is a slider. Move the slider thumb all the way to the right. This will show you all of those missing details.

Comment: I am inetersted where are 1-12 lines too... All data from the bottom of the screen is on the question's body.

Comment: I just told you how to view lines 1-12 in Xcode. Please read my previous comment again.

Comment: The slider's not in the normal place in XCode 6.1 -- that's the question!  :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's something I do to get the stack trace.

In your AppDelegate.m file:

```
void uncaughtExceptionHandler(NSException *exception) {

    NSLog(@"Call Stack: %@", exception.callStackSymbols);
}

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

    NSSetUncaughtExceptionHandler(&uncaughtExceptionHandler);

    // The rest of your method here...
}
```

Comment: Thanks. But what's wrong with xCode debugger? Is there a debugger?

Comment: For some reason, they decided that they didn't need to show details of the stack trace when an app crashes anymore. It's only from iOS 5 and up. No idea why they made that change. The code I posted brings back that stack trace printout.

Comment: Thank you again. I hate Apple. For black iPhone 5 too:)

Comment: And yes, there is a debugger. You can add breakpoints in your code and make sure the "Breakpoint" button is selected at the top left.

Comment: So, this is a breakpoint-debugger - not fully functional debugger.

Comment: Define fully-functional debugger.

Comment: Does anybody know how to enable a correct stack info on the debugger (without provided code)?

Comment: The provided code gives you exactly what you used to get with iOS 4.3 and before.

Comment: @SimonGermain I have no problem seeing full stack traces with the latest versions Xcode. I have never added any code like you posted. There is no need to add code just to see stack traces.

Comment: @rmaddy What version of iOS are you deploying to?

Comment: @SimonGermain I'm using Xcode 4.6. My project's Base SDK is 6.1 with a Deployment Target of 5.0. See the comment I just added to the question. The other trick is to go to the breakpoints pane in Xcode. Tap the + button in the bottom left corner. Choose to add an "Exception Breakpoint". Once added, right click on the exception breakpoint and choose to move it to "User".

Comment: @rmaddy Should not your comments be merged into an answer? They are helpful.